# Is it possible to perform case insensitive search in Cosmos DB Gremlin API?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, gremlin-server, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Does Gremlin API support the use of upper, lower, or any other string functions, or any other setting that allows case insensitive search?

Answer (score 1):

The current Gremlin Query Language does not have any case insensitive or regular expression capabilities built into the language. If the graph database you are using supports in line lambdas/closures then you can do it that way but a lot of graph DBs prevent that for security reasons among others. The Gremlin text predicates are case sensitive. Some graph DBs support integration with an external index such as Elastic Search. In those cases, case insensitive search is possible.